# Cant get fitBounds to work

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm not sure where to include the fit bounds as no matter where I put it, the map is centered on where initMap specifies which is halfway across the world instead of where the markers are.

Calls is just an object array that stores sets of lat/lngs

```
function initMap()
{
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 12,
        scaleControl: true
    }); 
}

// Place Markers on Map
function initMarkers()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Calls.length; i++)
    {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: Calls[i],
            map: map
        });
    }
}

function fit()
{
    var bound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i in Calls)
    {
        bound.extend(Calls[i].getPosition());
    }
    map.fitBounds(bound);
}

// Initialize GoogleMap on Page Load
window.onload = function()
{
    initMap();
    initMarkers();
    fit();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: This is minimal. I initialize the map and the markers and try to set the bounds to the markers. All of this is necessary.

Comment: You didn't provide the Calls array (or the HTML/CSS required).  I get a javascript error when I make up a Calls array based on your description (Calls is just an object array that stores sets of lat/lngs; I assumed that meant an Array of Objects, but...): `Uncaught TypeError: Calls[i].getPosition is not a function`

Comment: I'm making it in MVC so if you really want my code that encodes my model and loops through and sends the lat longs to the object array I can put it up but it seems kind of irrelevant.  Its basically like `function storeCoordinate(xVal, yVal, array) {
    array.push({x: xVal, y: yVal});
}`

Comment: I don't get the error you report with your posted code.  Did you test it?  I don't really need your complete model, just a [Minimal, Complete, **Tested** and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue as requested earlier.

Comment: Some of the times it gives me the above error and other times it shows me the map, but it is centered on what initMap says which is like Austrailia, while the markers are over in Missouri

Comment: If I fix the error reported (`Uncaught TypeError: Calls[i].getPosition is not a function`) in my code (which is what you posted), it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code generates a javascript error (not the one originally reported in the question, but that has been removed): `Uncaught TypeError: Calls[i].getPosition is not a function`.  `Calls` is an array of objects, so it won't have a `.getPosition` method.

```
function fit()
{
    var bound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i in Calls)
    {
        bound.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(Calls[i].lat,Calls[i].lng));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bound);
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var Calls = [{
  lat: 42,
  lng: -72
}, {
  lat: 40.7127837,
  lng: -74.0059413
}, {
  lat: 40.735657,
  lng: -74.1723667
}];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 12,
    scaleControl: true
  });
}

// Place Markers on Map
function initMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < Calls.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: Calls[i],
      map: map
    });
  }
}

function fit() {
  var bound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i in Calls) {
    bound.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(Calls[i].lat, Calls[i].lng));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bound);
}

// Initialize GoogleMap on Page Load
window.onload = function() {
  initMap();
  initMarkers();
  fit();
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Don't call `Calls[i].getPosition()` it is not a function.